# Is it possible to put two columns of checkboxes on PySimpleGUI to manipulate the values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, checkbox, edit, pysimplegui

I have been trying to develop a simple program that allows me to make changes to a pandas dataframe by checking and unchecking boxes laid out on a PySimpleGUI. So far, I have managed to create a `PySimpleGUI` by following the code provided in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773214/is-it-possible-to-insert-a-checkbox-in-a-pysimplegui-table).

However, I was having trouble adding two columns of checkboxes on the GUI. I wonder if there is any way of achieving it to manipulate the values in the "In_Possession" column of the dataframe by checking and unchecking the boxes on GUI. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def icon(check):
    box = (32, 32)
    background = (255, 255, 255, 0)
    rectangle = (3, 3, 29, 29)
    line = ((9, 17), (15, 23), (23, 9))
    im = Image.new('RGBA', box, background)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im, 'RGBA')
    draw.rectangle(rectangle, outline='black', width=3)
    if check == 1:
        draw.line(line, fill='black', width=3, joint='curve')
    elif check == 2:
        draw.line(line, fill='grey', width=3, joint='curve')
    with BytesIO() as output:
        im.save(output, format="PNG")
        png = output.getvalue()
    return png

check = [icon(0), icon(1), icon(2)]

headings = ['CHARACTER_NAME', 'TRUE', 'FALSE']


genshin_characters = {'Character_name':['Amber','Jean','Lisa','HuTao'],'In_Possesion':[True,False,True,False]}
genshin_chr_df = pd.DataFrame(genshin_characters)
data = genshin_chr_df.values.tolist()

treedata = sg.TreeData()
for character, in_possession in  data:
    if in_possession is True:
        treedata.Insert('', character, character, values=[check[1],check[0]])
    else:
        treedata.Insert('', character, character, values=[check[0],check[1]])

sg.theme('LightPurple')
sg.set_options(font=('Helvetica', 16))

layout = [
    [sg.Tree(data=treedata,headings=headings, auto_size_columns=True,
        num_rows=10, col0_width=20, key='-TREE-', row_height=48, metadata=[],
        show_expanded=False, enable_events=True,
        select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_BROWSE)],
    [sg.Button('Submit'), sg.Button('Quit')]
]

window = sg.Window('Character Collection', layout, finalize=True)
tree = window['-TREE-']

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Quit'):
        break
    elif event == '-TREE-':
        selected_row = values['-TREE-'][0]
        print(selected_row)
        if selected_row in tree.metadata:
            tree.metadata.remove(selected_row)
            tree.update(key=selected_row, icon=check[0])
        else:
            tree.metadata.append(selected_row)
            tree.update(key=selected_row, icon=check[1])
window.close()
```

Here is what I got when I put checkbox icons directly in the values of the tree object.
[The result of inserting checkbox icons directly in tree object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olUZ3.png)

And here is what I wanted to achieve

[image: 2]

Here are the values in the target dataframe.
[image: 3]

Comment: Maybe it will be better with three Column elements in same row, first one with all `character_name` Text elements, second one with all Radio elements which default as `'In_Possesion'` value, last one with all Radio elements which default as **NOT** `'In_Possesion'` value. Second Radio element is with the same group id as if of the third Radio element.

Comment: @JasonYang I have changed the part where I put the default values in the second and the third column and it seemed that I could not insert a Radio button directly in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Column` element to align child elements in following code.
Options `expand_x` and `expand_y` are required here to align elements, especially for different kind of elements.

Note: There're still something wrong if the values for option `expand_x` / `expand_y` of elements in same row of the layout are different, so a function added here to repack element with right pack information. It need more knowledge about the `pack` method of tkinter, so no more comment about it.

```py
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def repack(widget, option):
    pack_info = widget.pack_info()
    pack_info.update(option)
    widget.pack(**pack_info)

headings    = ['CHARACTER_NAME', 'TRUE  ', 'FALSE  ']
data_dict   = {
    'Name'  : ['Amber', 'Jean', 'Lisa', 'HuTao'],
    'State' : [True, False, True, False],
}
data_df     = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
names       = data_df['Name'].to_list()
settings    = data_df['State'].to_list()
sizes       = (20, 10, 10)

layout = [
    [sg.Column([[sg.Text(heading, size=size, justification='center' if i else 'left')]], background_color='blue')
        for i, (heading, size) in enumerate(zip(headings, sizes))],
    [sg.Column([[sg.Text(name, size=sizes[0], expand_y=True)] for name in names], background_color='blue', expand_x=True, expand_y=True, key='COLUMN 1'),
     sg.Column([[sg.Radio('', f'Radio {i}', default=setting, enable_events=True,     key=('Radio True',  i))] for i, setting in enumerate(settings)],
        element_justification='center', expand_x=True, expand_y=True, background_color='blue', key='COLUMN 2'),
     sg.Column([[sg.Radio('', f'Radio {i}', default=not setting, enable_events=True, key=('Radio False', i))] for i, setting in enumerate(settings)],
        element_justification='center', expand_x=True, expand_y=True, background_color='blue', key='COLUMN 3')],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

repack(window['COLUMN 1'].widget, {'fill':'y', 'expand':0})
repack(window['COLUMN 2'].widget, {'fill':'x', 'expand':1})
repack(window['COLUMN 3'].widget, {'fill':'x', 'expand':1})

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif isinstance(event, tuple) and event[0].startswith('Radio'):
        data_df['State'] = [values[('Radio True',  i)] for i in range(len(settings))]
        print(data_df, '\n')

window.close()
```

Blue background color here just help to show the situation of layout.

Without options `expand_x`/`expand_y` and method `repack`, you will get this layout
[image]

Without `repack`, you will get this layout
[image]

With `repack`, you will get this layout
[image]

Comment: Wow! That is exactly the GUI I wanted to make! I can't thank you enough! I will do my best to study the Column Element and the pack method of tinker. I truly appreciate you for what you have done for me :) You are a lifesaver!